# shell script: replace colon in file path

Tags: bash, shell

i'm using cygwin to run a few shell scripts under windows. I have this variable containing a Windows file path:

```
#!/bin/sh
pathToConfig=C:/workspace/proj1/etc/config.properties
```

Now i need to replace the `:` in that path by `\\:` to fit the path in there:

```
echo "create-jvm-options ${AUTH} \"-Dproperty.location=C\\:/workspace/proj1/etc/config.properties\"" >> ${commandFile}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `bash`,

```
echo ${pathToConfig//:/\\\\:}
```